# Select the row and column element of a dataframe and decide the regression variables

Tags: pandas, scipy, dataframe, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I have a pandas dataframe containing 10 columns and 1000 rows. I want to perform a multinomial logit regression. However, I want to use different independent variable based on the choice.

For example, I have the Y as "mode chosen" i.e car, bus, train etc. and I have attributes of the modes as X such as "car travel time" "bus travel time" etc.

I want to perform MNLogit wherein, when the chosen mode is car, the X must be car travel time and when the chosen mode is bus, the X must be bus travel time. So what I want to do is

```
if data.mode_chosen == "car":
         X = data["car travel time"]
elif data.mode_chosen == "bus":
         X = data["bus travel time"]
# .....
```

I want to access the Nth row and Mth column and find whether it is car or bus or train and then choose my dependent variables as per the choice.

PS: I am an amateur programmer and new to this forum, kindly let me know if I have not made my question clear.

Comment: Is `Y` your _dependent_ variable (that is what the name `Y` implies)? or one of the features (columns in X)?

Comment: Yes, I represented Y as the dependent variable and X's as the independent variable.

Comment: If your goal is to _predict_ Y , then it makes no sense to choose columns in X based on Y.  Think of your test set, where you do _not_ know Y. What are you going to do with it?

Comment: The idea behind MNlogit regression is to predict the probability of choosing an alternative over a set of discrete alternatives. So, say suppose the Utility of an alternative i.e "car" is a function of "travel time of car" and the Utility of an alternative i.e. "bus" is a function of "travel time of bus" and so on.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do what is often called a conditional logit (rather than multinomial logit).  Regardless, what you are trying to do is not going to work but I'm not 100% sure what it is you want to do.  I'd strongly suggest you add some example data and the actual logit model (including code) you are trying to estimate (from statsmodels?  from scipy?)

Comment: Released versions and master of statsmodels currently don't support this. There is a pull request to add `CLogit` (`acslogit` in Stata) for this use case. It will still take some time to get this functionality merged into statsmodels. You can ask on the statsmodels mailing list for details. `MNLogit` assumes parameter differ across choices but explanatory variables are identical.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think I am then looking for conditional logit and not a simple MNLogit. will try to elaborate my question with some examples.